# Why declaring a function on modal resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angular-ui, bootstrap-modal

I have 2 simple questions concerning this code example on modal angular-ui.

The code can be found [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), I also quote the interesting part:

```
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
};

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

So my first question is on, why do I need to declare a function on the `items`:

```
resolve: {
  items: function () {
    return $scope.items;
  }
}
```

and I can not do something like:

```
resolve: {
  items: $scope.items;
}
```

And my second question is why `items` is not a string with single quotes? How javascript doesn't confuse the key as a local variable?

Thank you for your explanations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question:

```
resolve: {
  items: function () {
    return $scope.items;
  }
}
```

`resolve.items` is a function.
`resolve.items()` returns (is) an array

```
resolve: {
  items: $scope.items;
}
```

`resolve.items` is an array
`resolve.items()` causes an error.

The need is because the framework expects a function to be called.

For the second question: JS != JSON. The syntax makes it possible. If you had written `items=...` instead `items: ...` then it would have been created as a **global** variable (or it would have raised an error, if strict mode were active)